# Can I redirect all old non-query string url's to new url

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all old url's which have a format of 'domain.com/property-search/ref-R3265882' to the format of 'domain.com/services/properties/for-sale/property/?ref=R3265882' but can't seem to get it to work

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^property-search/ref-$ /services/properties/for-sale/property/?ref=$1 [R=302,L]
```

and also

```
RewriteRule ^property-search/(.*)$ /services/properties/for-sale/property/?ref=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I am wanting to redirect all reference number with the old format to the new format.

Solution found (adding above in htaccess if using wordpress):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^property-search/ref\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /services/properties/for-sale/property/?ref=$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you describe:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?property-search/ref-(R\d+)$ /services/properties/for-sale/property/?ref=$1 [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 redirection first and only change that to a 301, once you are happy with the result. That prevents caching issues while you are still playing around.

That rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") located in the http host's document root, *if the interpretation of such files is enabled and the rewriting module is loaded...* You should prefer to use the real http server configuration in all cases you can, though, dynamic configuration files have a lot of disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, the url doesn't seem to be redirecting, good to know regarding 302 - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort it by doing this above wordpress current htaccess entries:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^property-search/ref\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /services/properties/for-sale/property/?ref=$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This implements the same logic as my answer. So the question is where the difference actually is? Maybe the location of your dynamic configuration file?